# How to close a relay contact at the same time every day using GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I want to close a relay contact automatically every day at 2 AM local time for 2 seconds, and then open. I can do this manually right now, but want to know where I should put the commands to do this automatically. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding a cron job. Do:

```
crontab -e
```

and you will probably want a line such as:

```
0   2   *   *   *     /path/to/your/script/that/holds/relay/for/2/seconds
```

That will trigger the script at 0 minutes after hour 2, every day of every month and every weekday.